# "On a été" vs "L'on a été"

Tags: grammaire

Quand peut-on utiliser la très littéraire forme "l'on a été" en lieu et place de "on a été". Les formulations sont-elles strictement interchangeables ?

Exemple issu de [l’actualité](http://www.bfmtv.com/politique/jean-marie-le-pen-trouve-qu-on-a-ete-tres-dur-avec-petain-875156.html) :

> L’on a été très sévère avec lui à la Libération. Et je n’ai jamais considéré comme de mauvais Français ou des gens infréquentables ceux qui ont conservé de l’estime pour le Maréchal.